# Why's my code wrong when looking for duplicates?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

I'm trying to solve this Leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate-ii/

I'm not sure why my code's incorrect.  I've followed the problem and tried to write it out as best as I could but it didn't work.

Can someone point out what I did wrong?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean containsNearbyDuplicate(int[] nums, int k) {
        boolean flag = false;
        int ans = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if(nums[i] == nums[j]) {
                    flag = true;
                }

                if(flag) {
                    ans = Math.abs(nums[i] - nums[j]);
                }

                if(ans <= k) {
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Can you be more specific? Describe actual and desired behavior.

Comment: please provide an example input and tell us where your code fails.

Comment: The difference between `i` and `j`, not between what's at those indeces. Re-read the problem statement. (p.s., if you think about it for a second `nums[i] - nums[j]` will always be 0)

Comment: You're never resetting `flag` so once you've found two identical elements it will most likely return true if there are more elements following. Let's take their last example {1,2,3,1,2,3} and k = 2: once you're at i = 0 and j = 1 `flag` will become true but because the index difference (if calculated correctly) would be  greater than k you'd continue. Eventually you'd be at i = 1 and j = 2 and even though the values are different you'd calculate the index difference because `flag` is still true at that point.

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.abs(nums[i] - nums[j])` is the problem

You're checking if the values of the numbers are `<= k` and instead you should check on the indices.

Do as follow:

```
public boolean containsNearbyDuplicate(int[] nums, int k) {
   boolean flag = false;
   int ans = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
         if(nums[i] == nums[j]) {
            if( Math.abs(i - j) <= k) return true;
         }
      }   
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Your way also solves the other problem (`flag` is never reset) but you may want to point that out as well (and remove `flag` and `ans` for your code as well, while you're at it)

Comment: You miss `=` in ` if( Math.abs(i - j) <= k) return true;` becaue at the problem `at most`

Comment: @mooga thanks! Updated

Comment: wow, ok I see what I did wrong now, thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

You initialise `int ans = 0;`
Let's pretend that `i = 0; j = 1;`
`nums[i] != nums[j]  /// flag still == false.`

Then you  check if ans <= k. 
And as ans is still 0 - it will be lower that key.

You should add extra check here:

```
 if(ans != 0 && ans <= k) {
     return true;
 }
```

Moreover you call Math.abs() on numbers, not on indexes.